# Javascript string and character comparision

Tags: javascript

Why does `'Mystery!' <= 'Z'` equal `true` but `'the' <= 'Z'` equal `false` but both
 `'Mystery!' >= 'A'` and `'the' >= 'A'` equal `true`. How does such comparision work?

Comment: Because `'B' < 'a'`. Characters are usually (on most systems) in this order: `..., A, B, ..., Z, ... , a, b, c, ...`

Comment: it depends on characters' codes. In fact what gets compared are the codes of the symbols.

Comment: Compare the lowercased version of both operands.

Comment: @kindUser Just closing it without even reading the duplicate candidate. How typical.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The "on most systems" part is misleading. JavaScript always uses the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set for strings.   What might vary by source, user and time is the [locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) but the binary comparison operators always use the UTF-16 lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper case letters before lower case letters.

`M` = ascii value 77
`Z` = 90

```
77 < 90
```

`t` = 116
`Z` = 90

```
116 !< 90
```

See more here: www.asciitable.com

Comment: JavaScript doesn't use ASCII for built-in text datatypes. I'm not aware of any language that does.

Answer (score 3):

it's comparing the UTF-16 code for the string value.  Try the same comparisons with charCodeAt method to understand what's happening here

```
'y'.charCodeAt() <= 'Z'.charCodeAt()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt